# Write method to return fourth element in List

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I currently am attempting this.

```
let L = [2; 4; 6; 8]

let fourth listx  = List.nth(listx 3);;

fourth L;;
```

but I want `'a -> 'a` (list to list) not `int -> 'a`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like

```
let fourth listx = List.nth listx 3
```

This gives a signature of `'a list -> 'a` which is I think what you want.  The key difference is the absence of brackets which don't do what you are expecting in this case

Comment: Ill accept when the timer is finished. Why do the paren make a difference?

Comment: @jth41 the brackets make `listx` a function which returns a list rather than an argument of `nth`

Answer (score 0):

```
let fourth x = (fun x -> [x]) (List.nth x 3)
val fourth : x:'a list -> 'a list
```